# loading my php page from login page doesn't give error but loading it from some other page in my application does

Tags: javascript, php, server, xampp

When I try to load this above php page from my login page (index.php), there is no error but when I try to load it from any other page in my application after login, it gives me an uncaught syntax error on the console. It points to the script and says that the php variable $name is not defined.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
session_start();
$_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'attendance_system';

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Failed to connect: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    $success = false;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM student";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["email"] === $email && $row["password"] === $password) {
            $name = $row["name"];
            $age = $row["age"];
            $criteria = $row["attendance_criteria"];
            $course = $row["course"];
            $college = $row["college_name"];
            $attendance = $row["attendance"];
            $success = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($success === false) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
}

if (isset($_POST["signup"])) {

session_start();
$_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email1"];
$email = $_POST["email1"];
$password = $_POST["password1"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$criteria = 100;
$course = null;
$college = null;
$attendance = 0;
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'attendance_system';

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Failed to connect: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO student SET email = '$email', name = '$name', age = '$age', password = 
 '$password' ";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
}
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Attendance Manager - Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/skeleton.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="../media/icon.png">
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div class="left">
        <button id="menuButton" onclick="openMenu()">≡</button>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
        <div>
            <div id="month">
            </div>
            <div id="year">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="day">
        </div>

        <img id="icon" src="../media/icon.png" alt="App Icon" width="48" height="48">

        <div id="name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <a id="info" href="../html/index.php">l</a>
    </div>
</header>

<main>
    <menu>
        <a href="home.php">Home</a>
        <a href="subjects.php">Subjects</a>
        <a href="criteria.php">Edit Attendance Criteria</a>
        <a href="help.html">How to Use</a>
        <a href="developer.html">Developer Information</a>
        <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </menu>
</main>

<section>
    <div>
        Name :
        <span id="user_name"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        Email :
        <span id="user_email"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        Age :
        <span id="user_age"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        Password :
        <span id="user_password"></span>
    </div>
</section>

<footer>
    <div class="left">
        Attendance Manager<br>2020 ©
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <span>
            Official Page -
        </span>
        <span>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/AlokPur32580593?s=08">
                <img src="../media/twitter.png" alt="Twitter Icon" height="48px" width="48px">
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <a id="privacyPolicy" href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
    </div>
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.referrer === "http://localhost/AttendanceManager/html/index.php") {
        var name = "<?= $name ?>";
        var age = "<?= $age ?>";
        var email = "<?= $email ?>";
        var pasword = "<?= $password ?>";
        var criteria = "<?= $criteria ?>";
        var course = "<?= $course ?>";
        var college = "<?= $college ?>";
        var attendance = "<?= $attendance ?>";
        localStorage.setItem("name", name);
        localStorage.setItem("age", age);
        localStorage.setItem("email", email);
        localStorage.setItem("password", pasword);
        localStorage.setItem("criteria", criteria);
        localStorage.setItem("course", course);
        localStorage.setItem("college", college);
        localStorage.setItem("attendance", attendance);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your footer `<script>` always runs and always expects `$name` to be filled, then you'll have to check whether the session was logged in. If it isn't, redirect the user to the login page, or specify defaults.

Also, you should probably rewrite the SQL you're using to authenticate the user. First, save the password as a hash. Second, use a `WHERE` statement to fetch any rows that match the email and password, instead of looping through the results in your application.

You probably also want to fix the `var pasword` typo, and I advise you to rename the `$success` variable to something more descriptive, like `$loggedIn`. This might not be critical for this particular purpose, but it's a good thing to get into the habit of properly naming your variables.

Comment: I don't want to run the footer script every time. I only need it to run once per user i.e once after the user has logged in from the login page. After that as user navigates back and forth within the pages of my application, and comes back to the home page, it should not run again. Can you help with that ? I have implemented all the other changes you recommended.

Comment: If the `localStorage` calls are only made after a login, and if it's ok to leave those keys unset in other parts of the application, then you can simply wrap the entire JavaScript block in a PHP conditional statement. You could set `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;` after a successful login, and then wrap the `localStorage` bit in an `if ($_SESSION['logged_in'])` block.